# PHP CodeIgniter get the highest price

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this array here

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

The numbers 1, 2 and 3 represent an id of a value....in the database I have all of those id have a price (fee) and all the fees are different...what I am trying to do is get the highest fee and return one value...

$query = $this->db->get_where($this->tbl_name, array('id' => $id));
$data = $query->row();

How would I adjust the code above to find the highest fee and return that row?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->db->get_where($this->tbl_name, array('id' => $id))->order_by("fee", "DESC")->row();
```